# error C4430: AND error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'

Tags: c++

I am having these two errors.

```
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
```

i already checked the solution from internet, every body recommend to `#include <string>` and using `std::string` instead of `string`, this is my header file. I applied the solutions but problem is still there. This is my code

```
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Student& s);
friend class StudentList;

public:

    Student(int id = 0,std::string name = "none");
    virtual ~Student();
private:
    std::string name;
    int id;
    Student* next;  
RCourseList* rCList;
```

and this is my program's upper portion

```
#ifndef STUDENT_H
#define STUDENT_H
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "RCourseList.h"
```

This is `RCourseList.h`

```
#ifndef COURSELIST_H
#define RCOURSELIST_H

#include "RCourse.h"

class RCourseList

{
public:
    RCourseList();

private:
    RCourse* rhead;
};

#endif // RCOURSELIST_H'
```

Comment: On which line are these errors occurring?

Comment: Please reduce this to an example someone can compile.  Also what are the line numbers for these errors?  Is this home work?

Comment: on last line RCourseList* rClist; before i included this pointer in my header file code was running fine.

Comment: @ShahjahanKhokher Then it seems likely that the answer is in RCourseList.h, could you post that?

Comment: .#ifndef COURSELIST_H
#define RCOURSELIST_H

#include "RCourse.h"

class RCourseList
{
    public:
        RCourseList();

    private:
        RCourse* rhead;
};

#endif // RCOURSELIST_H.

Comment: Well, `#ifndef COURSELIST_H` should be `#ifndef RCOURSELIST_H` but that's probably not the course of this error. Basically we need to see everything that the compiler does. Can you **edit** the above question to include all the relevant code. Basically everything up to the point where the first compiler error occurs.

Comment: @john That's working woaaww

Comment: @ShahjahanKhokher Do you also have a header file called CourseList.h? Does that header file start with `#ifndef COURSELIST_H`. That should give you the clue.

Comment: @john yeah john i do have 'COURSELIST_H' as well

Comment: can you post an answer with correction.

Comment: @ShahjahanKhokher Right, I'm writing this up as an answer now. Please accept the answer when I'm done. Glad to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your header file RCourseList.h, has an error in its *include guard*

```
#ifndef COURSELIST_H
#define RCOURSELIST_H
```

it should be

```
#ifndef RCOURSELIST_H
#define RCOURSELIST_H
```

The reason this is a problem is because you have another header file called CourseList.h, that header also starts with an include guard.

```
#ifndef COURSELIST_H
#define COURSELIST_H
```

So CourseList.h defines the macro COURSELIST_H and this prevents the CourseList.h file from being included twice (in a single compilation) because `#ifndef COURSELIST_H`is true on the first include but will be false on a second include.

But because your RCourseList.h wrongly starts with `#ifndef COURSELIST_H` including CourseList.h will also prevent a later RCourseList.h from being included.

In short, name your include guards after your header file names. Be very careful about this otherwise you get this kind of error.

Or you could replace the traditional include guard with the non-standard but widely supported `#pragma once`, like this

```
#pragma once

#include "RCourse.h"

class RCourseList

{
public:
    RCourseList();

private:
    RCourse* rhead;
};
```

`#pragma once` does exactly the same as the traditional include guard but without the possibility of this kind of error.

Comment: as a beginner this is priceless knowledge for me, Thanks alot sir.